# batch fie to remove special characters in text file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am using the below code to replace double quote from source file that we receive from a third-party vendor application. This is a legacy application that we still support. We receive many files and of late we are running into data issues and getting difficult to figure out what the issue might have been.

replacequotes.ms

```
!text
!backup=no

#1. remove double-quotes at start of line 
#2. remove double-quotes immediately preceded by a tab
#3. remove leading and trailing spaces
~1(^|\9)~1(' '*)('"'?)(' '*)
~1

!newpass

#1. remove double-quotes at end of line 
#2. remove double-quotes immediately followed by a tab
#3. remove leading and trailing spaces
(' '*)('"'?)(' '*)~1(\9|$)~1
~1

!newpass

'""'
'"'
```

batch file

```
SET ENV=%1
SET FILENAME=%2
SET BIN=C:\Bin
SET FILE=C:\data\quote.txt

%BIN%\msub %BIN_DIR%\replacequotes.ms %FILE% 2>nul
 
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO EXITOK
EXIT
:EXITOK
EXIT 0
```

This code uses msub application and looks for any double quotes in the file and replace them for instance "User" -> User. When an error occurs and double quote in the file are not replaced it would break the downstream application which is trying to process these files. How to add better error handling to throw user friendly error.

Comment: I've never heard of `msub` and I can't find any information about it online, but the problem isn't with your batch script.

Comment: It seems to me as if you're looking for information specific to msub's particular regular expressions etc. As I've no idea what this program is, have never heard of it, and there's no tag for it, you will be lucky to get that here. The only other alternative would be that you were instead looking for a different solution using another utility or scripting language. That would however, be an off topic code request, so could you please clarify exactly what you're needing.

Comment: `msub` appears to be a SourceForge project that has not been updated since 2013. If you copy/paste into the question as text a few example lines and the desired output, someone will probably have a suggestion. This looks like some simple regex expressions. `cmd` does not handle regexes, but PowerShell does. If you are on a supported Windows platform, PowerShell will be available.

Comment: [jrepl](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6044) might be a good alternative if you want to stay in batch. It provides full REGEX capabilities.